# Audio Download manager for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio-player

I want to download audio files(mp3) from Web.I do not have much idea how to make that download manager.please provide any source if available

Comment: Itunes? Otherwise, provide some information as to *exactly* what you want, what you have tried so far, and what isn't working. People here on SO normally frown upon questions that ask the answers to `provide any source code if available` without showing any effort in the question. This could cause your question to be down-voted if it isn't corrected through an edit (one of the gray links under the tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Download Helper](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/tree/master/C15/03-Download%20Helper) link and get helped.

Comment: I am newbie in IOS ..please suggest some IOS books links also!